# Unauthorised (401) error while creating grails demo app

Tags: grails, groovy

I have installed grails on my system with following details
Grails Version: 3.2.2
Groovy Version: 2.4.7
JVM Version: 1.7.0_60
But, I am getting unauthorised error when I try to create demo app with following command.

```
$ grails --stacktrace create-app demo



Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Unauthorized (401) (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized (401)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.handleStatus(HttpTransporter.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:276)
    at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:53)
    at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:49)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.MavenProfileRepository.<init>(MavenProfileRepository.groovy:53)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.createMavenProfileRepository(GrailsCli.groovy:333)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:234)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
 Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Unauthorized (401)
```

Not sure if I have done some silly mistake here but please let me know if anyone is aware of this issue.

Comment: have you set this  export GRAILS_OPTS="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Xverify:none"

Comment: @DipakThoke : yes, GRAILS_OPTS is added to env config.

Comment: This might be the problem of jvm?

Comment: @Sunil I have resolve exception like your by upgrading java to 1.8+ version

Answer (score 1):

Not sure as what must be the exact reason for this issue but its somewhere related to maven. When I deleted settings.xml(This is needed for my other maven projects) of .m2 directory, I am able to create demo app.

Answer (score 0):

Our company has its own internal repository proxy server, and needed to update my password for that server in my `settings.xml` file, because I had changed my password on the server recently:

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <password>
```